# Trouble with getElemenstByClass() function in JSoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm writing an app that fetches text sms from html of website smsmaza.in, for which I'm using Jsoup to parse HTML. Following is the code which is troubling me

```
            BLOG_URL="http://www.smsmaza.in/"; 
            Document document;
            document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).timeout(12000).get();
            Elements texts=document.getElementsByClass("sms");
```

When I print value of texts.size() it comes to be zero, which means nothing is selected. What is the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Here is the complete program :- http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/20317090

Comment: Did you check whether that above class you are trying to get exists in the `Actual HTML source`. Try to see `Right click on the page--->View page source-->search your classname`

Comment: yes it is there, you can check also

Comment: can you try `Elements texts=document.select("[class^=sms]")` and get `size()`?

Comment: Not working, it is showing 0 only. But document.title(); is working properly

Comment: not sure.I am not able to load contents of your link.cause it's blocked inside my company

Comment: Okay. Thanks for giving it a try :)

Comment: Elements texts = document.getElementsByClass("sms");
            String sms = texts.first().text();

Comment: have u tried `Elements texts = document.select("p.sms");` and then `texts.size()` ? @PramodJodhani

Comment: @Shoshi No not working.

Comment: @user1888162 No not working, I've added the complete program, if you can help

Comment: Hey! I was able to figure out the problem. Actually every time the mobile version of smsmaza.in was being fetched which didn't have any <p> element with class "sms" and while I was opening the site from my browser, desktop version was being opened. Thank you mates for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 1):

from your code i have used:

```
Document document=Jsoup.connect("http://www.smsmaza.in/").timeout(12000).get();
Elements texts=document.getElementsByClass("sms");
Log.e("sms", Integer.toString(texts.size()));
```

and logcat show me `10` sms classes are selected. so it is working well.

you should not block `setContentView`. and in your bellow code:

```
if(texts.size()>0){
  int i=0;
  while(i<texts.size()){
     result[i]=texts.get(i).text();
     //you should increase your i here
  }
}
```

you should increase `i++` in `while` loop.
if it doesn't help, try this:

```
int i = 0;
for(Element element : texts){
    result[i] = element.text();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Sir, when I added this line
Log.e("sms", Integer.toString(texts.size()));
it showed me zero in the LogCat. The problem you figured was mistakenly done by me while experimenting.

Comment: after which line u have use `Log.e("sms", Integer.toString(texts.size()));` for checking ?

Comment: after 
Document document=Jsoup.connect("http://www.smsmaza.in/").timeout(12000).get();
Elements texts=document.getElementsByClass("sms");